# Alchemy linke error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: alchemy

I trying to use Adobe Alchemy Compiled C++ code to swc. At the beginning it work pertty good, but when I add more c++ code, Unfortunately, getting it to link ends up producing a link-time error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Scanner.nexttoken(Scanner.java:657)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.getNextToken(Parser.java:673)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.lookahead(Parser.java:631)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.match(Parser.java:434)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAsmDirective(Parser.java:5128)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAsmStatementOrExpr(Parser.java:4949)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAsmStatement(Parser.java:4927)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseStatement(Parser.java:4211)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAnnotatedDirectiveOrStatement(Parser.java:5645)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:5594)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseDirectives(Parser.java:5985)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseBlock(Parser.java:4411)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseBlock(Parser.java:4397)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseFunctionCommon(Parser.java:1631)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseFunctionDefinition(Parser.java:6898)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAnnotatableDirectiveOrPragmaOrInclude(Parser.java:5916)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAnnotatedDirectiveOrStatement(Parser.java:5712)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:5594)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseDirectives(Parser.java:5985)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseBlock(Parser.java:4411)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseBlock(Parser.java:4397)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseClassDefinition(Parser.java:7542)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAnnotatableDirectiveOrPragmaOrInclude(Parser.java:5920)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseAnnotatedDirectiveOrStatement(Parser.java:5712)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:5594)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseDirectives(Parser.java:5985)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseBlock(Parser.java:4411)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parseBlock(Parser.java:4397)
at macromedia.asc.parser.Parser.parsePackageDefinition(Parser.java:8053)
```

"Java heap space" means Java heap speace not enough, it need to set jave option like "java -Xms128M -Xmx512M -jar..", but I can't find where to set the option in alchemy.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Oldmannt

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

- Don't compile with debugging flags (`-g` and friends).  This causes it to generate a ton of extra code, and often causes it to run out of memory.
- Increase the heap-space arg (`$jmemmax`) in `$ALCHEMY_HOME/achacks/gcc`.

Comment: to paleozogt:Thank you very much!

I have checked, There is no debugging flags in my compile.
 
I increase the heap-space as you said, but the link error appear all the same. It hit me down... I will try alchemy in windows version,